# MFC VC++: CMFCButton::SetFaceColor does not change background(face) color

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CMFCButton on a CFormView. I want it to have a particular background color. I came across CMFCButton::SetFaceColor which I thought would do that. But unfortunately it didnt work. May be I'm misunderstanding the "Face" terminology here. Is that the case?

Here's my code:

```
m_btnCopy.SetFaceColor(RGB(255,0,0),true);
m_btnCopy.SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,255));
```

and output:

[image]

Comment: Are you getting tripped up by...."Note that the background is not filled when the CMFCButton::m_bTransparent member variable is TRUE."

Comment: @rrirower I checked that member and its false by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This setting is quite archaic and is ignored by modern theme engines.
Most likely your application was generated by Visual Studio wizard and contains something like:

```
CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerWindows));
```

You can try to remove this line to disable custom MFC themes but the button will not look good anyway, after `SetFaceColor` it will be drawn in classic theme.

Comment: It worked and as you said the button doesnt look good. I'll try overriding the OnDraw methods. thnks

Answer (score 1):

almost same method but slightly better look.

```
  m_btnCopy.EnableWindowsTheming(FALSE);
  m_btnCopy.m_nFlatStyle = CMFCButton::BUTTONSTYLE_FLAT;
  m_btnCopy.m_bTransparent = false;
  m_btnCopy.SetFaceColor(RGB(255,0,0),true);
  m_btnCopy.SetTextColor(RGB(0,0,255));
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people suggest to use m_bDontUseWinXPTheme = TRUE. It works due to the following code in afxbutton.cpp:

```
void CMFCButton::DrawBorder(CDC* pDC, CRect& rectClient, UINT uiState)
{
   <snip>

   // Draw 3d border:
   if (m_nFlatStyle != BUTTONSTYLE_NOBORDERS)
   {
       if (m_bWinXPTheme && !m_bDontUseWinXPTheme && CMFCVisualManager::GetInstance()->DrawPushButtonWinXP(pDC, rectClient, this, uiState))
```

The 'DrawPushButtonWinXP' isn't invoked anymore when m_bDontUseWinXPTheme is set. You get though an ugly old style button.

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes.

`mCMFCBtn.m_bGrayDisabled = FALSE;`

`mCMFCBtn.m_bDontUseWinXPTheme = TRUE;`

`mCMFCBtn.m_nFlatStyle = CMFCButton::BUTTONSTYLE_FLAT;`

`mCMFCBtn.SetFaceColor(RGB(255, 0, 0), TRUE);`

`mCMFCBtn.SetTextColor(RGB(0, 0, 0));`